# memory sharing -- between sytem call & interupt handler

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I read following link 
[Linux Device Driver Program, where the program starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917198/linux-device-driver-program-where-the-program-starts/12923107#12923107)

as per this all system calls operate independent to each other.

1> Then how to share common memory between different system call & interrupt handler.
but there should be some way to allocate memory ... so that they have common access to a block of memory.

2> Also which pointer to allocate the memory? so that it is accessiable by all ?

Is there some example which uses driver private data ?

Comment: *"system calls operate independent to each other"* - That is not true; you misconstrue what was written.  The user app needs to call *open()* first, which sets up an internal structure to coordinate user access with system calls.  The *file descriptor* that is returned is actually a tag to retrieve this structure on subsequent sys calls, i.e. you have to provide this *file descriptor* for *read()*, *write()* and *ioctl()* operations.  The *close()* deallocates this structure and further accesses.  The device driver also maintains state info for each device it handles. All OSes use this scheme.

Comment: @user1870619 I think you might be better off starting with some background reading.  I think that the answers would drop into place if you read [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/).