# why we make all struct static in kernel programming

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

While trying Linux kernel programming i found that for every built-in structures we use static.
I believe (as i understood) all device's has their own scope inside corresponding driver's space and it stays live until we disconnect the device. Then why do we use static structs all the time?

Please explain. thanks you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static functions in Linux device driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423333/static-functions-in-linux-device-driver)

Comment: `static` is a *linkage* issue.  Anything that applies to functions applies to variables, structures, or whatever kind of thing you can create in **C**.

Comment: Most structures are not `static`. Please be more specific.