# File operation in drivers and struct declaration

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

i am trying to figure out how the code behind a basic kernel driver works.

I have the following struct:

```
    static struct file_operations fops =
{
   .open = dev_open,
   .read = dev_read,
   .write = dev_write,
   .release = dev_release,
};
```

And my dev_open function is defined as:

```
static int     dev_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
```

Now Im also familiar with the fact that the prototype for opening a device file is defined in the linux/fs.h:

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.10/include/linux/fs.h#L1517

Here is the specific line from that link:

```
int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
```

Now my question is what is the relationship between `.open = dev_open,` and `int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);`
which is defined in linux/fs.h? Is it passing the address of dev_open to the function pointer `int (*open)` defined in the linux/fs.h? There must be some relation or what is the point of defining the struct fops as type "file operation"?

A similar question was asked and answered here but i feel that my question was left out:
[File operations in drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663692/file-operations-in-drivers)

Thank you

Comment: The line `int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);` defines a **field** for the `struct file_operations`. Name of the field is `open`, type of the field is a **pointer to function**, which accepts 2 arguments (of type `struct inode*` and `struct file*`) correspondingly and returns `int`.

Comment: It may help to know that the member initializer `.open = dev_open` means exactly the same thing as `.open = &dev_open`. C has weird rules for the unary `*` and `&` operators on functions. In both case, `fops.open` is being initialized to point to the `dev_open` function.

Comment: In `struct file_operations`, The `open` member needs to be declared explicitly as a function pointer `int (*open)(struct inode *, struct file *);`. Members of a struct or union type can have "pointer to function" type, but not "function" type, so the `open` member cannot be declared as `int open(struct inode *. struct file *);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is more about C than the Linux kernel.

Members of structure or union types cannot have *function* type, but they can have *pointer to function* type. For example, in the Linux kernel, the `open` member of `struct file_operations` needs to be declared with a *pointer to function* type: `int (*open)(struct inode *, struct file *);`. Declaring the member as `int open(struct inode *, struct file *);` is an error.

In this variable definition in Linux kernel code:

```
static struct file_operations fops =
{
   .open = dev_open,
   .read = dev_read,
   .write = dev_write,
   .release = dev_release,
};
```

Incidentally, the above should normally have the `owner` member initialized like so:

```
   .owner = THIS_MODULE,
```

The expressions `dev_open`, `dev_read`, `dev_write` and `dev_release` are *function designators* being used as *assignment expressions* to initialize the members of `fops`. A function designator is an expression that has *function* type. Unless it is the operand of `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator is converted to a *pointer to function* type. Therefore, the above definition of variable `foo` is exactly equivalent to:

```
static struct file_operations fops =
{
   .open = &dev_open,
   .read = &dev_read,
   .write = &dev_write,
   .release = &dev_release,
};
```

(Don't forget to also initialize `.owner = THIS_MODULE,`.)

There, the function designators *are* operands of the unary `&` operator and so are not converted to *pointer to function* types implicitly, but the `&` operator is converting them to *pointer to function* types explicitly.

After the above initialization of `fops`, `rc = fops.open(inode, file);` indirectly calls `dev_open(inode, file)` and assigns the return value to `rc`. You may sometimes see this written in an older style: `rc = (*fops.open)(inode, file);`. They both do the same thing. The operand of the function call operator `(` `)` is in fact *always* a pointer to a function. In the case of `rc = (*fops.open)(inode, file);`, `fops.open` has a *pointer to a function* type. `(*fops.open)` dereferences `fops.open` to a *function* type but since `(*fops.open)` is a *function designator* it is implicitly converted back to a *pointer to function* type before the function call. Similarly, in the direct call `rc = dev_open(inode, file);`, `dev_open` is a function designator and so has a *function* type, but is implicitly converted to a *pointer to function* type before the function call.

Comment: I believe my confusion is with the left hand side of the equation. Is it true that `.open = dev_open` is the short form of `.(*open)(struct inode *, struct file *)=dev_open` ?

Comment: @programmer25 No, `.(*open)(struct inode *, struct file *)=dev_open` is invalid syntax. The `open` member already has a type. It just needs to be initialized (or assigned) with a value of compatible type. The `open` member has type `int (*)(struct inode *, struct file *)` (a _pointer to function_ type). `dev_open` has type `int (struct inode *, struct file *)` (a _function_ type) but is converted to `int (*)(struct inode *, struct file *)` (a _pointer to function_ type matching the `open` member), so is compatible with the `open` member.