# How linux identify a particular file system to execute system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, vfs

Can please summarize the events/steps that happen when I try to execute a read()/write() system call. How does the kernel know which file system to issue these commands.

Lets say a process calls write().
Then It will call sys_write().

Now probably, since sys_write() is executed on behalf of the current process, it can access the **struct task_struct** and hence it can access the **struct files_struct** and **struct fs_struct** which contains file system information.

But after that I am not seeing, how this **fs_struct** is helping to identify the file system.

Edit: Now that Alex has described the flow...I have still doubt how the read/write are getting routed to a FS, since the VFS does not do it, then it must be happening somewhere else, Also how is the underlying block device and then finally the hardware protocol PCI/USB getting attached.

A simple flow chart involving actual data structures would be helpful

Please help.

Comment: *"...when I try to execute a read()/write() system call"* --  The file has to be opened first.  See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501437/how-does-open-works-for-normal-file-and-device-drivers/14513460#14513460

Comment: If you are looking for a chain of function calls from all the way from read() to the appropriate file-system/hardware driver, its unlikely you will find one. Its mostly function-pointers and callbacks. One interesting technique a senior of mine often used was to deliberately perform a null-pointer dereference in the last/deepest/lowest function in the flow and get the stack-trace (list of last-to-first function calls) from the resulting Linux kernel oops messages.

Comment: @xeonphi, your original question here was "how the VFS identifies which file system should handle a `read`/`write` call". How that call propagates down into the block device layer and then to ATA/AHCI/etc. is a different question. If you are having trouble figuring it out, you can post another question for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer is based on kernel version 4.0. I traced out some of the code which handles a `read` syscall. I recommend you clone the Linux source repo and follow along in the source code.

1. Syscall handler for `read`, at `fs/read_write.c:620` is called. It receives a file descriptor (integer) as an argument, and calls `fdget_pos` to convert it to a `struct fd`.
2. `fdget_pos` calls `__fdget_pos` calls `__fdget` calls `__fget_light`. `__fget_light` uses `current->files`, the file descriptor table for the current process, to look up the `struct file` which corresponds to the passed file descriptor number.
3. Back in the syscall handler, the file struct is passed to `vfs_read`, at `fs/read_write.c:478`.
4. `vfs_read` calls `__vfs_read`, which calls `file->f_op->read`. From here on, you are in filesystem-specific code.

So the VFS doesn't really bother "identifying" the filesystem which a file lives on; it simply uses the table of "file operation" function pointers which is stored in its `struct file`. When that `struct file` is initialized, it is given the correct `f_op` function pointer table which implements all the filesystem-specific operations for its filesystem.

Comment: Hi, thanks I went through the flow on Free electrons linux source...But I still don't quite understand....There has to be a mechanism to identify which file system type the read should be routed...may be not in VFS...then some where else...Can you please help with that. 

So essentially, how does the read get routed to particular FS, then to the underlying block device and finally the Hardware protocol, PCI, USB etc.

Comment: Pay close attention to the last sentence of my answer. Each `struct file` has  a table of function pointers which are called for reads, writes, and so on. The table which is used depends on the filesystem which the `struct file` belongs to. If the file is on an ext2 filesystem, then it will get the function pointer table for ext2. If it is on an NTFS filesystem, then it will get the function pointer table for NTFS. So calling `file->f_op->read()` will "automatically" get you into the correct `read` function *for the filesystem you are using*.

Comment: Let me give you an example. Look at `fs/ext2/file.c:93`. (I really recommend you clone your own copy of the kernel source rather than using Free Electrons. Make sure you install `cscope` as well for searching the source.) This is the `f_op` table for ext2 files. As you can see, when `file->f_op->read()` is called for an ext2 file, the call will actually go to `new_sync_read`. That goes through the `f_op` table again to `generic_file_read_iter`, and from there to `do_generic_file_read`. If the needed page is already cached in memory, `do_generic_file_read` uses it.

Comment: If not, it goes through the `address_space_operations` table defined at `fs/ext2/inode.c:880` to `ext2_readpage`. That goes into the generic block read function `mpage_readpage`, which is passed a function pointer to `ext2_get_block`. It calls `ext2_get_block` to identify the exact location of the desired block on the underlying block device.

Answer (score 0):

Each filesystem registers itself to VFS. When a filesystem is mounted, its superblock is read and VFS superblock is populated with this information. Function pointer table for this filesystem is also populated at this time. when file->f_op->read call happens, registered function from the filesystem is actually called. You can refer to text in http://www.science.unitn.it/~fiorella/guidelinux/tlk/node102.html