# How does kernel understand, which driver module function handles read/write/etc?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I found a [couple](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/07/05/devhelloworld-a-simple-introduction-to-device-drivers-under-linux.html) of [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112474/A-Simple-Driver-for-Linux-OS), where it is shown how to make your own hello-world driver.

I supposed that function names should be hardcoded (for example, when you read from device, you use `read` function, etc).

But everywhere are used functions names like `hello_read` ([first article](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/07/05/devhelloworld-a-simple-introduction-to-device-drivers-under-linux.html?page=2)) or `device_file_read` ([second article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112474/A-Simple-Driver-for-Linux-OS)), when describing what should happen when i `cat` device.

How does kernel understand, what function he should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is `struct file_operations`. You will find it defined in both examples. This structure describes which function callbacks should be called (by providing pointers to those functions) when some operation on a file is performed (like a read, write or open).

The pointer to this structure is passed when your driver registers to some subsystem. In case of a miscdriver (first example), it's set in `struct miscdevice` structure which is then passed to `misc_register` function. In case of a character device (second example), it's directly passed as an argument to `register_chrdev`.

The `file_operations` structure is described in 2nd example you provided - read it carefully.

Comment: `struct file_operations` is only used by character device drivers.  For block and platform devices, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917198/linux-device-driver-program-where-the-program-starts/12923107#12923107

Comment: @sawdust: That's true but the idea is the same.