# Write to a UIO Device

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I understand the basics behind a UIO driver, as described in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/uio-howto.html). The part I'm missing is how to write data from the user space program *back* to the device driver. My guess is that you'd write this data to the `mmap` region, but then how to do you let the device driver know it should read said memory?

Ultimately I'm trying to write a block device that can be implemented by a user space program. I've got the block device code stubbed out and working: https://github.com/wspeirs/usbd. My thought was that UIO was the most efficient way to transfer blocks/sectors between the block device and the user space program. Is this the wrong way to go about communicating with the block device driver from user space? Should I be using `sysfs` or some other communication mechanism?

Comment: How is your code related to a UIO driver when it does not even call **uio_register_device()** or define a **uio_info** structure?  There is already framework for block devices.  Since you're not using that framework, then you can't fully utilize your block device, e.g. install a filesystem on it.  BTW your code does not conform to kernel coding style.

Comment: @sawdust I have not yet added the uio portions as I do not understand how to get data from the user space program to the kernel driver. What is the block device framework you're referring to that I'm not using? Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917198/linux-device-driver-program-where-the-program-starts/12923107#12923107

Comment: @sawdust [I'm using](https://github.com/wspeirs/usbd/blob/12307abc4e99b83c0028a4c502dadfe878348011/usbd.c#L116) the `block_device_operations` struct you mention in that post... is that the "framework" you're talking about?

Comment: You have *defined* a `struct block_device_operations` but you're not using it effectively.  If you want *"the most efficient way to transfer blocks/sectors between the block device and the user space program"* then consider implementing a [`direct_access` block device operation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/dax.txt).  Your implication of also using UIO with this driver is irrational.

Comment: minus 1 nasty answer. You might consider that somebody asking a question is looking for information, not insults.

Comment: A filesystem in user space is called FUSE. Efficient way to transfer large amounts of data between app and physical device is DMA. So, is your device physical or not?

Comment: @ddbug no, this is all virtual. The map solution given below seems to work very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIO is designed so that user space bypasses the kernel to communicate with a hardware device. That does not seem to fit your needs.

In a standard Linux block device, you can use `mmap()` to write data to your block and `msync()` to indicate to the driver which regions you have written.

Comment: plus 1 pleasant answer.